# ZF2 dissable layout in view templates (phtml files)

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-view, zfcuser

i was trying to dissable layout in my override of zfc user login page

here is what i tried so far :

```
$this->viewmodel()->getCurrent()->setTerminal(true);

$this->viewmodel()->getRoot()->setTerminal(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no way to setTerminal(true) so you have to create an extra NULL layout
that has only the

```
<? echo $this->content; ?>
```

then use following script to change the layout to new null layout in your phtml file

```
$this->viewmodel()->getRoot()->setTemplate('layout/null');
```

dont forget to add 'layout/null' in your template path stack in your module config file